# Сборка программы java

Tags: java, bat, jar

Есть задача которую я написал в ходе обучения. К ней дается следующая задача вот такого содержания :

Собрать программу, написанную в ходе предыдущего задания, в запускаемый Jar файл. Собрать каталог готовой программы и сделать .bat/.sh файл для запуска программы. Директория программы должна иметь следующую структуру:

```
program_folder
|--- program.jar
|--- run.bat
```

Как собрать jar файл в идеа я разобрался, а вот как создать bat файл не совсем(гуглил но не понял). То есть суть моего вопроса как создать bat файл и как организовать ту структуру которая описана выше. Просто я не понял что выше обозначает "|---". Наверное очень глупый вопрос, но как есть.

Comment: Создать `bat` - ПКМ -> Создать текстовый файл -> Меняете название файла и расширение с `.txt` на `.bat` -> Готово. Открываете его обычным текстовым редактором и пишете в него команду запуска приложения. `|---` - Это означает что файлы `.jar` и `.bat` находятся в папке. Я бы советовал собирать проект через `maven`

Comment: "|---" означает собрать в каталоге program_folder как сам jar'ник, так и bat'ник. Но как создать bat-файл, - самому интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура, которая быа описана у вас - это вывод команды `tree Path\to\program_folders /f /a` в командной строке:

```
├───program_folders
│       program.jar
│       run.bat
```

Код `bat` файла:

```
set PROGRAM_FOLDERS=Path\to\program_folders

call java -jar %PROGRAM_FOLDERS%/program.jar
```